# Change UITableViewController background color

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I was implementing search in a `UITableViewController`, so i read a lot of tutorials and they said to implement `UISearchController`.

For this i have taken a `UITableViewController` and embedded in a `UINavigation​Controller` then i assign `UISearchController.searchBar` to `tableHeaderView`.
Search is working and everything is perfect.

But when i scroll down `searchBar` scrolls down leaving a blank space which has different color then my tableview color.

How can i change it. I am unable to do so yet.[image: see the color difference]

Comment: set both same color as your main view color so its not create different color space in device

Comment: Select your `TableView` in the storyboard. From the _Attributes inspector_ scroll down to _View_ section and select the **background** as ***default***.

Comment: so it means we have to give tableview default color ... no other option is there ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple to implement way is use uiviewcobtroller put searchbar on top and below that put simple tableview now you can solved ur problem .... dont put searchbar in tableview.
Hope u will resolve it  .. cheers
Thanks